# What is the matcher of any object of particular class in mockitokotlin2?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockito

there is `any()` in mockitokotlin2 but it's any object. I need a matcher for any object of MyClass, like `org.mockito.Matchers.any(MyClass::class.java)`

is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin) you can specify your type as a type argument of `any`:

```
org.mockito.kotlin.any<MyClass>()
```